# cakePhp 1.3.3 on IIS web.config working but no styles

Tags: iis, cakephp, url-rewriting

I am trying to deploy a cakephp app to iis but am having trouble with the re-writes. I have added the cake recommended web.config file to the root and it seems to work with the clean urls, however it is not finding any styles even for the cake config index.php. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: By styles you mean CSS files? Take a look at the source of a page that's missing the styles. Look for the path of the CSS files it tries to load. That should narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you dont have rewrite enabled, try http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/filippo.toso/2008/01/29/cakephp-on-iis

or don't use "pretty" url's

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft IIS doesn't allow the functionality of mod_write which is a must when you are using Cake PHP. You can even use something , which is equivalent to the same on microsoft server,i.e IIS. Check out the link below, it might be of help : 
http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

Answer (score 0):

Using this Web.config, my app works fine. Is important too, add 777 permissions on cake folder.

https://github.com/fabiotnt/Utils/blob/master/PHP/Cake-Web.config